# Multiple Functions on Same Elements Using JQuery

Tags: html, jquery

Hopefully I'm asking this properly; feel free to correct.

I have the following code which makes a timeline appear on my page upon mouseenter into that div and disappear upon mouseleave from that div to another div.

```
var nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.easing.easeOutCubic = function (x, t, b, c, d) {
    return c*((t=t/d-1)*t*t + 1) + b;
  }
  
  for(i=0; i<=nums.length; i++){
    $(".tl-item" + nums[i]).mouseenter(function(){
      for(j=0; j <= nums.length; j++){
        $(this).find('#timeline'+ nums[j]).stop(true, true).fadeIn(100, 'easeOutCubic');
      }
    });
  }

   for(i=0; i<=nums.length; i++){
    $(".tl-item" + nums[i]).mouseleave(function(){
      for(j=0; j <= nums.length; j++){
        $(this).find('#timeline'+ nums[j]).stop(true, true).fadeOut(1000, 'easeOutCubic');
      }
    });
  }
});
```

What I'm looking to do next is when the timeline is visible click on a year so a modal pops up with a chart.  I tried to first see if the code would take a click event but nothing happened.  What could be the reason why the click event isnt registering?

```
$(document).on('click','.test li', function(){
   alert($(this).text());
```

```
 <div id="timeline1">
              <ul class="test">
                <!-- <li data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalnew" data-whatever="1970" class="openmodal"><a >1970</a></li> -->
                <li class="active"><a href="" class="timelineYear">1970</a></li>
                <li><a href="" class="timelineYear">1971</a></li>
                <li><a href="" class="timelineYear">1972</a></li>
                <li><a href="" class="timelineYear">1973</a></li>
                <li><a href="" class="timelineYear">1974</a></li>
                <li><a href="" class="timelineYear">1975</a></li>
                <li><a href="" class="timelineYear">1976</a></li>
                <li><a href="" class="timelineYear">1977</a></li>
                <li><a href="" class="timelineYear">1978</a></li>
                <li><a href="" class="timelineYear">1979</a></li>
                <li><a href="" class="timelineYear">1980</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
```

I have my jquery package at the end of my body tag and tried moving it to the head tag and tried keeping it both in the head and at the end of the body and no luck.  Also instead of alert I tried console.log and nothing appeared in the console.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Any ideas would be quite welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You have some syntax error on your click event. I've tested this for you as a starting point. As you begin using jQuery, I'll suggest you to use the last version available today query-3.6.0.min.js .

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    //
    $(document).ready(function() {

      $(document).on('click','.test li', function(){
         alert($(this).text());
         return false;
      });
    
      $.easing.easeOutCubic = function (x, t, b, c, d) {
        return c*((t=t/d-1)*t*t + 1) + b;
      }
  
      for(i=0; i<=nums.length; i++){
        $(".tl-item" + nums[i]).mouseenter(function(){
          for(j=0; j <= nums.length; j++){
            $(this).find('#timeline'+ nums[j]).stop(true, true).fadeIn(100, 'easeOutCubic');
          }
        });
      }

      for(i=0; i<=nums.length; i++){
        $(".tl-item" + nums[i]).mouseleave(function(){
          for(j=0; j <= nums.length; j++){
            $(this).find('#timeline'+ nums[j]).stop(true, true).fadeOut(1000, 'easeOutCubic');
          }
        });
      }
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="timeline1">
 <ul class="test">
   <!-- <li data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalnew" data-whatever="1970" class="openmodal"><a >1970</a></li> -->
   <li class="active"><a href="" class="timelineYear">1970</a></li>
   <li><a href="" class="timelineYear">1971</a></li>
   <li><a href="" class="timelineYear">1972</a></li>
   <li><a href="" class="timelineYear">1973</a></li>
   <li><a href="" class="timelineYear">1974</a></li>
   <li><a href="" class="timelineYear">1975</a></li>
   <li><a href="" class="timelineYear">1976</a></li>
   <li><a href="" class="timelineYear">1977</a></li>
   <li><a href="" class="timelineYear">1978</a></li>
   <li><a href="" class="timelineYear">1979</a></li>
   <li><a href="" class="timelineYear">1980</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response and tips especially since my reputation still isnt high enough to give you an upvote for the effort.  Unfortunately it did not work.  I wonder if my CSS could be conflicting with the jquery somehow.  Wish I could share my entire code with you to help troubleshoot but it's quite lengthy.